# Rails app serving .scss files required in application.css, which is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use the Rails asset pipeline in my app in a way described at (http://www.mattboldt.com/organizing-css-and-sass-rails/), but am noticing some weird behavior which I believe is causing my styles not to be applied.

The structure of my assets directory is as such:

```
+-- assets
    +--- images
    +--- javascripts
    +--- stylesheets
        +--- styles
            - global.scss
            - scaffolds.scss
        - application.css
        - main.scss
```

I've set up my application.css file to require only itself and a `main.scss` file in the same app/assets/stylesheets directory:

```
*= require_self
*= require main
```

This `main.scss` file contains all of the other files I'd like to import:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "styles/global.scss";
@import "styles/scaffolds.scss";
```

However, it seems like none of my styles are being applied when I try to view the project in my browser. The peculiar thing I'm noticing is that my browser is showing that it's downloading both an `application-self-<hash>.css` file, and a `main-self-<hash>.scss` file. The first file is mostly blank, and looks as follows:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *


 */
```

The `main-self-<hash>.css` file contains all of the custom CSS I've imported into it from other files. I was under the impression that it should actually be compiled into the application.css file instead of being compiled into css and served in its own file. In any case, the effects of this are clear - my styles aren't being applied. I'm not sure where to look to resolve this. Can anyone help point me in the right direction, please?

[EDIT] It seems like externally-sourced (from a URL) CSS files do get compiled properly, and their styles are applied. For instance, I added `@import url('http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css');` to my `main.scss` file and made use of it by applying one of the CSS file's classes to one of my `div` elements. The style was applied.

Comment: all stylesheets compile into one only in production. in development each file is included separately. If your browser sees your styles, it means that rails did everything that has to be done. Now it's only html and css, and css is not working. BTW, Firefox with FireBug plugin is great at debugging css, js and stuff

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll try that next. Good to know that what I'm seeing is expected behavior as far as all files being served, but there's still the issue of why the CSS from that main file isn't taking hold.

Comment: One other thing I noticed - I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem and Safari is complaining that there are a few unexpected CSS tokens coming from bootstrap. Could that be affecting the other styles in my CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

In Development mode the assets (css, js) are rendered as is in separate files.

They are combined into one file in production mode when you run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

You can check browser "Requests" and "Sources" in Developer tools to make sure if the files are being loaded.

Comment: Good to know Hassan, thank you. So now the question becomes, why isn't the CSS from my main.css file taking hold on the page? @IvanSelivanov suggested in a comment above that I grab Firefox with Firebug above to debug my CSS and figure out what's going on.

Comment: are the respective css files being loaded ? You can also check this in chrome, it will look something like this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors-files/sass-sources.png

Comment: If not make sure you have included the gem 'sass-rails' in Gemfile and <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %> in application.html.erb or your main layout file

Comment: My application.html.erb file includes `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. And all of the files being loaded are `application.self-<hash>.css`, `jquery.self-<hash>.js`, `jquery_ujs.self-<hash>.js`, `main.self-<hash>.css`, and `turbolinks.self-<hash>.js`.

Comment: rename application.css to application.css.scss. Also @import is css declarative, for rails sass you should use "*= require bootstrap.css" etc

Comment: Still no dice. If you look at the link at the top of my question, though, you'll see an alternate way to arrange your scss files in the asset pipeline. Even going back to the vanilla way of doing things didn't work.

Comment: ok, so the @import is used to include sass partials , ref: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: try using "*= require_tree ." and  "*= require_self" in application.css.scss file to see if all the files are loaded or not ... else perhaps there could be a configuration issue with rails asset pipeline not compiling your assets on runtime

Comment: Ok, now I'm really concerned. I created a brand-new rails application from scratch and did nothing but generate a scaffold and alter the CSS file to change a <div> to be blue with light blue text, and even THAT isn't working. FWIW I'm on ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 4.2.3, if it helps anything.

Comment: The guide does indeed cite @import being used for Sass partials, but it seems to work with regular old .scss files too. Still, I renamed my styles/*.scss files so that they have an underscore at the beginning of the name, to follow convention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solves the entire problem, but I do know that `application.css` should be named  `application.css.erb` or the requires will not work.

From the [Rails spec](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

> "The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means if you add
>   an erb extension to a CSS asset (for example, application.css.erb),
>   then helpers like asset_path are available in your CSS rules:

**Note about assets**

Since all compiled assets are served from /public/assets/, adding a subdirctory structure in the source tree under stylesheets serves only add points of possible failure in the code.

Comment: Thanks Val. That's odd, considering my generated rails project came with application.css.scss. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. The generators create a minimal structure. The  application.css.scss file one such example. Good luck.